# Boolean operations on generalized polygons with circle segments as edges

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry, cgal

I need to work with generalized polygons where edges are not only line segments, but circle segments too and holes can occur. So I decided to use

[CGAL Boolean set operations](https://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Regularized_Boolean_Set-Operations)

with the setup:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                   Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Circle_2                                  Circle_2;
typedef Kernel::Line_2                                    Line_2;
typedef CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2<Kernel>         Traits_2;

typedef CGAL::General_polygon_set_2<Traits_2>             Polygon_set_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_2                       Polygon_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_with_holes_2            Polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                                 Curve_2;
typedef Traits_2::X_monotone_curve_2                      X_monotone_curve_2;
typedef Traits_2::Point_2                                 Point_2t;
typedef Traits_2::CoordNT                                 coordnt;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits_2>                     Arrangement_2;
typedef Arrangement_2::Face_handle                        Face_handle;
```

I have to compute unions of large numbers of polygons (up to about 200,000) and subtract from such unions again up-to 100,000-200,000 polygons. So speed is an important concern. In the setup above an exact kernel is used, where the number type of Point_2t is of the form a0 + a1 sqrt(root) where a0, a1, root are rational numbers. To speed things up, I tried to compile everything with `CGAL::Kernel<double>` instead, but this lead to assertion errors in the CGAL code.

*Is it true, that the Boolean ops on polygons routines make an exact number type kernel necessary, and can not work with an inexact `CGAL::Kernel<double>`?*

If there is no possibility for further speedup in this CGAL library:

*Is there another (C++)-library for working with generalized polygons (having also circle segments as edges) and computing boolean ops on them which is faster? (For example because it uses only double-values as point coordinate values?)*

Comment: You can compile in non-debug mode suppressing the assertions, using, say, CGAL::Cartesian<double>. This is not recommended. Using an exact kernel is not a whim of the authors of the code. It serves a necessary cause.

Comment: @EfiFogel Thank you, Professor Fogel, for this first-hand advice. In fact using CGAL::Cartesian<double> in release mode just was an exchange from assertion failures to segmentation faults. But, as a positive side node: Using the exact kernel in release mode gave me on a big union of polygons (~165,000) a 2x speed improvement and many single calls to CGAL::do_intersect where sped up even 10x (rough estimate, as I let the calculation never finish in debug mode).

Comment: @EfiFogel Do you think, it is possible to have a library (already written or yet to write) that works on other principles on the problems mentioned in the post, that would be 2 or 4 times faster than your CGAL Arrangement based library? For only straight edge polygons I noticed, that there are 3 - 4 libraries on the net, that are advertized as being much faster than CGAL and which give visually well appealing results (among them a boost library). But this is of course without circle segment edges. Do circle segments make your approach so to say "the unbeatable gold-standard" among algorithms?

Comment: I guess that the segmentation fault is a direct consequence of using a limited precision number type. You can run the same program on a (very) simple case that does not have degeneracies and verify that it woks.

Comment: I haven't searched for other libraries and I'm truly unfamiliar with other options. However, I would be careful when choosing a library other then CGAL that claims to be faster than CGAL, as it might not be robust. For more information read https://www.cgal.org/exact.html